# Get key and value from json string limited with openwrt

Tags: json, bash, openwrt

Im checking inside a openwrt with very few shell commands to see If is possible to filter json string to have the values.

For example 
{"address":"192.168.2.2","user":"user1","groups":"permissions"}

I receive from curl the string and I need to separate values to pass vars to other commands.

For now Im checking some examples but not works

```
#!/bin/sh
. /usr/share/libubox/jshn.sh 
json_init
json_load '$(cat $STRING)'
json_get_keys keys
for k in $keys; do 
   json_get_var v "$k"
   echo "$k : $v"
done
```

But produce error "Failed to parse message data"

My problem is justly that I cna't use jq, or python to choose data, so only solution is to separate first.

Suggestions?

Comment: `'$(cat $STRING)'` isn't expanded so you're trying to parse `$(cat $STRING)` as a JSON object. What is that `json_load` ? The JSON data should most likely not be passed as arguments but rather fed on its stdin

Comment: https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/jq

Comment: thanks @Aaron is true, the correct is $(echo $RESPONSE)

Now only I need to filter the line generated user : user1 to select all after "user :"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found other form more clean to do the same

```
eval $(jsonfilter -s $STRING -e 'ADDRESS=@.address' -e 'USER=@.user')
echo "address=$ADDRESS user=$USER"
```

With this form I can filter every value how parameter, without jq or python function.

Comment: You should add double-quotes around `$STRING`, otherwise it will break on JSON data containing spaces. If it's not in quotes, it's expanded then split into IFS-separated tokens (only the first of which would be associated with your `-s` option assumedly), if it's in double quotes it's expanded but considered as a single token, if it's in single-quotes it's not expanded and is considered as a single token.